# Fill empty cells with Fixed Value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to extract a number every 20 rows and fill the next 19 cells with it. My current formula for extracting is `=IF(MOD(CELL("row",A20),20)=0,AV21,"")` and I have tried `=IF(BJ21="",LOOKUP(1,1/($BJ$1:$BJ$10000<>""),$BJ$1:$BJ$10000),BJ21)`
to lookup the value if there is a value, but I cannot get it to start from the beginning. It goes to the bottom and takes the last value.

This is a picture of how it looks now and how it should look:

[image: Current and desired result]

Comment: Would be helpful to see what columns and rows this starts at

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Fill_20()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test") '<-- Update

Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim LR As Long, LC As Long
LR = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LC = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For i = 1 To LR Step 20
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(i, 1), ws.Cells(i + 19, LC)).Value = ws.Range(ws.Cells(i, 1), ws.Cells(i, LC)).Value
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Gpc6mYg   this is where they actually are as rows columns, also the days to jump are customizable so I can do either 20 25 30.